# How to select a particular element in DOM and not its parent element using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension, which can be used to inspect elements on any webpage. It should have two functionalities -

1. On clicking, it should return the html markup and css styles of
   that particular element.
2. On hover, it should highlight the particular element (just like
   inspector in chrome dev tools)

I have achieved first part, but i am not able to achieve the second part.
I am new to JS and **trying to achieve the hover task using plain JS, without any jQuery.**

This is my content script file

```
console.log("Chrome extension loaded");

var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var divs = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.h:hover { background-color: #83aff7; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

// for click events and functionality
for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++)
{
    all[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this));
    });
}

// for hover event
for (var i = 0, ma=divs.length; i <ma; i++)
    {

        (divs[i]).addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        this.classList.add('h');
        });

        if(this.parentNode && this.parentNode.hasAttribute("class"))
        {
        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        this.parentNode.classList.removeClass('h');
        }); 
        }
```

The clicking events part is working fine but in hover event, the color of parent as well as the element changes. **Only the color of particular hovered element should change.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your css style

`style.innerHTML = '.h:hover { background-color: #83aff7; }';`

This says if an element with class h is being hovered, set background color. You are adding the "h" class to the parent with

`$(this).parent().addClass('h');`

CSS RULE 1 (if parent is of class h AND parent is hovered, color background):

`style.innerHTML = '.h:hover *{ background-color: #83aff7; }';`

CSS RULE 2 (if parent is of class h AND element is hovered):

`style.innerHTML = '.h *:hover{ background-color: #83aff7; }';`

Make sure to pick the rule that is appropriate for you.

Working JS Fiddle with both examples (your original CSS is the third box): https://jsfiddle.net/nsevpqd9/

If you do not want to edit your CSS style at all then add the class to the element itself, not the parent:
`$(this).addClass('h');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually i want as soon as element is hovered, its background color should change but also the parent color should return to normal. I have edited the hovering part of code, it is changing color but the parent color is still intact when hovering a child. Please suggest how i can improve this code further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "addEventListener" to achieve "mouseover" to the element